# Induction proofs on MSets

Tags: coq

I'm trying to use MSet library in a Coq development and I need a `map` function, which is absent from the library, but can be implemented using `fold`, as usual.

In the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/1bb47d5a07e91e27384175fdb2710e34), I've put a simplification of what I'm working on, full of axioms, just to get straight to the point.

My problem is to prove a property of the following `map` function:

```
Definition map (f : Exp -> Exp) s
  := MSet.fold (fun a ac => MSet.add (f a) ac) MSet.empty s.
```

Which uses `fold` from Coq MSet library. The property that I want to show is:

```
  Lemma map_lemma : forall s f e, In e (map f s) -> exists e', In e' s /\ e = f e'.
  Proof.
     induction s using set_induction ; intros ; try fsetdec.
```

Which is intended to show that if an element `e` in the set `map f s`, then exists another element `e'` in `s`, s.t. `e = f e'`. My difficulty is to prove the inductive case, since the induction hypothesis produced by `set_induction` does not seems useful at all.

Could someone provide me any clues on how should I proceed?

Comment: A note about sets don't include a `map` operation is because it only makes sense as such if the mapped function is injective and order-preserving. For all other cases, you are talking about "the image of a set under f", which has slightly different properties.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think there is a problem in your definition of `smap`. You must swap `MSet.empty` and `s`, otherwise you can prove:

```
Lemma snap_trivial : forall f s, smap f s= s.
Proof.
  intros. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

With the right definition, you can use the `fold_rec` lemma that is adapted to this kind of goal.